# powershell split keeping only the 2 first part of string

Tags: powershell, split

i'm new in powershell
i have a file that contains OU paths separates by "/"
i'd like to only keep the 2 first element of each string

example:

```
paris/sales/salers/14tharrdt

london/comptability/office1
```

would give

```
paris/sales

london/comptability
```

i googled and found many things, but no way to do this simple thing

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `-split` to split the string on the `\` character, select the first two elements and join them together:

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_file_path'
$content | foreach {
    ($_ -split '/')[0, 1] -join '/'
}
$content | Set-Content 'your_file_path'
```

---

Or, if you prefer using `regex` here a solution without split ([demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lM7pG3/1)):

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_file_path'
$content | foreach {
    $_ -replace '(.*?\/[^\/]+).*', '$1'
}
$content | Set-Content 'your_file_path'
```

Comment: I like easy scalable/modifiable `($_ -split '/')[0 .. 1] -join '/'`

Answer (score 2):

Like:

```
$a = "paris/sales/salers/14tharrdt"
$b = $a.Split("/")[0] + "/" + $a.Split("/")[1]
$b
```

Improvement would be if call Split once and save it to a variable

Comment: No need to store it in a variable since you can do `$a.Split("/")[0, 1] -join '/'` ;-)

Comment: Yes, I was hesitating to copy it from your answer :)